# 2D Instantiated object stops moving when used with timer

Tags: unity-game-engine, timer, instantiation

Hello I'am trying to make a system that instantiate and object, and the moves it to a set of waypoints. When i use intantiate in the Start() function it travels like intended through the waypoints, but when i add the instantiate line to my update() function it only travels a little while and then stops, the same goes for the rest of the instantiated objects. It has something to do with timer i guess, but i have tried a few approaches, but they all lead to the same thing. Hope someone can help.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class waypointTest : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private Transform[] waypoints;

public GameObject waypointInvader;
GameObject go;        
private int nextUpdate = 1;
public float speed = 5f;
private int waypointIndex;




void Start()
{               
    
}
void Update()
{
    if (Time.time >= nextUpdate)
    {
        nextUpdate = Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.time) + 1;
        go = Instantiate(waypointInvader, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;            
    }        

    
    if (go.transform.position != waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position)
    {
        Vector3 newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(go.transform.position, waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        go.transform.position = newPos;
        if (newPos == waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position)
        {
            waypointIndex += 1;
        }
        if (waypointIndex == waypoints.Length)
        {
            waypointIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are loosing the reference to the object you want to move.

If instantiate is inside `Start()`:

1. `go` is set to be the instantiated object
2. `go` is moved to every waypoint
3. `go` is moved to the very first waypoint
4. `go` is moving through the waypoints again

If instantiate is inside `Update()`:

1. `go` is set to be the **first** instantiated object
2. `go` is moved to a few waypoints **until** `Time.time >= nextUpdate` returns true
3. `go` is set to be the **second** instantiated object and will loose its reference to the **first** `go`
4. The **first** `go` stops moving
5. The **second** `go` starts moving
6. Repeat

One way to solve this problem is to give the moving object `go` its own movement script. That way you just have to instantiate `go` and it will handle its movement by itself. If `go` does not know where the waypoints are you can give it to it after instantiating (For example `waypointInvader` is a prefab). E.g.:

```
if (Time.time >= nextUpdate)
{
    nextUpdate = Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.time) + 1;
    go = Instantiate(waypointInvader, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
    go.GetComponent<GoMovement>().ListOfWaypoints = waypoints;
}
```